# Export virtual accounts list from WinSSHD server control panel

Tags: bitvise

I want to know if someone can assist I need to export a list of all virtual accounts we have configured on the WinSSHD, I have tried running a few powershell script with no avail.

I have run a export on the WinSSHD control panel, but this exports the settings in a .wst file format and not csv

WinSSHD VirtAccounts:

[image]

Comment: Try to start an elevated Command Prompt (or PowerShell), navigate to the SSH Server's installation directory and run the command: `BssCfg settings exportText`. This exports the complete SSH Server settings in a textual format where it might be easier to find.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work BssCfg is not a recognized command, we are running WinSSHD ver5.23

Comment: The current version is 8.45, so yours is old. Any reason you cannot upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @harrymc. I can't comment, hence the answer. There's one more thing that needs to happen. Navigate to the  installation directory. Use an elevated command prompt (PowerShell wouldn't work for my installation). Run: bsscfg settings exporttext > myexportfile.txt

This pipes the output to a file rather than just to the console window. You can then open the file in your chosen text editor.